# Dividing each element from a dataframe by specific elements of a second dataframe

Tags: r, apply, sapply

I have two data frames:

```
x = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(1:6,1000,rep=TRUE)))
y = t(data.frame(apply(x, 2, sum)))
```

How do I divide each element form x per column by the element in y in the column with the same name. Also, what would be a better way to write y?

I have tried a nested apply:

```
apply(y, 2, function(y){
    sapply(x, function(x) (x/y))
})
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `scale`:

```
scale(x, center=FALSE, scale=y)
```

or `sweep`:

```
sweep(x, 2, y, FUN='/')
```

Answer (score 4):

A better way to write `y` will be

```
y <- colSums(x)
```

And in order to "divide each element form x per column by the element in y" you can try

```
mapply("/", x, y)
```